# Comparing 3d tensor and 4d tensor Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following U-Net which I use to segment grayscale PNG images.

```
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


OVERALLSIZE = int(float(input('Choose the number of images you want (<5635) : ')))
PATH = input('give absolute path to image')
TESTSIZE = int(float(input('Choose the number of the data you want to use as test (<5635) : ')))

######################################################################################################################

images = [img for img in os.listdir(PATH + '/Xtrain') if img.endswith('png')]
# put random_state to 1
images = shuffle(images,random_state = 0)
masks = [name[:-4]+'_mask.png' for name in images]

images, masks = images[:OVERALLSIZE], masks[:OVERALLSIZE]
images_, masks_  = [cv2.imread(PATH + '/Xtrain/' + img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.int) for img in images], \
                   [cv2.imread(PATH + '/ytrain/' + msk, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.int) for msk in masks]

######################################################################################################################


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = np.asarray(images_[TESTSIZE:])/255., \
                                   np.asarray(masks_[TESTSIZE:]), \
                                   np.asarray(images_[:TESTSIZE])/255., \
                                   np.asarray(masks_[:TESTSIZE])



x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 420, 580], name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 420, 580], name='y_')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def convoer(inputs, shape, flag):
    W = weight_variable(shape)
    b = bias_variable([shape[3]])

    temp = shape
    temp[2] = shape[3]

    Wa = weight_variable(temp)
    ba = bias_variable([shape[3]])

    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(inputs, W) + b)
    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv, Wa) + ba)
    pool = max_pool_2x2(conv)

    if flag: return pool
    elif not flag: return conv

def upconvoer(inputs, shape, height, width):
    W = weight_variable(shape)
    b = bias_variable([shape[3]])

    temp = shape
    temp[2] = shape[3]

    Wa = weight_variable(temp)
    ba = bias_variable([shape[3]])

    up = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, height, width)
    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(up, W) + b)
    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv, Wa) + ba)

    return conv

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides = [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

def U():
    inputs = tf.reshape(x, [-1,420,580,1])

    pool1 = convoer(inputs, [3,3,1,32], True)

    pool2 = convoer(pool1, [3,3,32,64], True)
    pool3 = convoer(pool2, [3,3,64,128], True)
    pool4 = convoer(pool3, [3,3,128,256], True)
    conv5 = convoer(pool4, [3,3,256,512], False)

    conv6 = upconvoer(conv5, [3,3,512,256], 73, 53)
    conv7 = upconvoer(conv6, [3,3,256,128], 145, 105)
    conv8 = upconvoer(conv7, [3,3,128,64], 290, 210)
    conv9 = upconvoer(conv8, [3,3,64,32], 420, 580)

    W10 = weight_variable([1,1,32,1])
    b10 = bias_variable([1])

    conv10 = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(conv9, W10) + b10)

    y = conv10

    return y

y = U()

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: X_train, y_: y_train})
```

At the **cross-entropy step** I try to multiply a 3d Tensor y_ [batch, grayscale_in_height, grayscale_in_width] and 4d tensor y [batch, height, width, channel].

I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Incompatible shapes for broadcasting: (?, 420, 580) and (?, 420, 580, 1)
```

I've tried to reshape y at 3 different locations: in the *U* function, at the very beginning where it is defined and within cross_entropy but none had worked.

Comment: Can you post more context, so we can tell for which op in particular the broadcast is failing?

Comment: Have you tried to slice the second tensor by removing it's last dimension? here's how: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice

Comment: Instead of slicing just use the squeeze function.

Answer (score 0):

stick a tf.newaxis into the tensor.

```
x = x[:,:, :, tf.newaxis]
```

or use tf.squeeze to get rid of the extra axis in y.

```
y = tf.squeeze(y, axis=-1)
```